# A way of Matrix decomposition

Tags: matrices, tensors, matrix-decomposition

if $M$ is $3\times 3$ sysmmetric matrix, $\det(M)=0$, it seems that we can decompose $M$ by this way:$M^{ij}=a^ib^j+b^ia^j$.
Is it correct? How to prove it?

Comment: This is true for symmetric matrices that are $3 \times 3$ or smaller, but not true in general.

Comment: Yes, I found it when I was considering 3x3 matrices, can you tell me how to prove it or introduce involved theory?

Comment: Can you please say what exactly it is that you would like to prove?

Comment: Actually I was wrong about my earlier comment: it is not true for **every** $3 \times 3$ matrix.  In particular, this fails to hold for matrices that are either positive or negative semidefinite.

Comment: Addition: det(m)=0

Comment: In which case this equality will hold?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105606/discussion-between-hao-huang-and-omnomnomnom).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the entries of $M$ are real numbers.

$M$ can be written in the form $M^{ij} = a^i b^j + b^j a^j$ if and only if for the column-vectors $a = (a^1,\dots,a^n)$ and $b = (b^1,\dots,b^n)$, we have
$$
M = ab^T + ba^T = \pmatrix{a &b}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{a &b}^T.
$$
As a consequence of [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), there exist vectors $a,b$ such that this holds if and only if $M$ is symmetric and one of the following conditions hold:

1. $M$ has rank $2$ with one positive eigenvalue and one negative eigenvalue,
2. $M$ has rank $1$,
3. $M = 0$.